# match with java 8 regex string form any language

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to match with java 8 regex string form any language

as long as it includes letters, digits and `.` or `-`

```
String s = "בלה בלה";
String pattern= "^[\\p{L}\\p{Digit}_.-]*$";
return s.matches(pattern);
```

what am i missing as this code returns null for hebrew valid string.

Comment: Wait, you have a space in the string, but not in the pattern. Try `String pattern = "(?U)^[\\w.\\s-]*$"`

Comment: *what* does return null? as `String#matches()` returns primitive `boolean`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add a whitespace to your pattern, and use `\w` instead of `\p{L}\p{Digit}_` while passing the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag:

```
String s = "בלה בלה";
String pattern= "(?U)[\\w\\s.-]*";
System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
// => true
```

See the [Java demo](http://rextester.com/CCCP22957)

Since the pattern is used inside `String#matches()` method, the `^` and `$` anchors are not necessary. If you plan to use the pattern with the `Pattern#find()` method, enclose the pattern within anchors as in the original code (`"^(?U)[\\w\\s.-]*$"`).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?U)` - the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` embedded modifier flag  that makes shorthand character classes Unicode aware (you may see what `\w` matches in this mode)
- `[\\w\\s.-]*` - zero or more:

  - `\w` - word chars (letters, digits, `_` and some more)
  - `\s` - whitespaces
  - `.` - a dot (no need to escape it inside a character class)
  - `-` - a hyphen (no need as it is at the end of the character class)

Comment: excellent! I absolutely was not aware you can turn the unicode search in java regex. thank u

Comment: Am I missing something, or should the `.` not be escaped like `\\.`?

Comment: @Lino No, it should not.

Comment: @shmosel: no need for `^` and `$`, the pattern is used in `.matches()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you explain me why? as the dot matches almost every character, doesn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Was I sleep talking again?

Comment: @Lino: [`.` is](https://regex101.com/r/mhsKyi/1) not equal [to `[.]`](https://regex101.com/r/mhsKyi/2).